# App Store crash report

Tags: ios, crash

My app got rejected from store and saying it's crashing.  But we cannot reproduce the crash, not with simulator nor the devices.  And looking at the crash report doesn't mean much.  Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the first crash report:

```
Date/Time:       2011-04-28 19:14:10.181 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x624f7473
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b2b72a prepareForMethodLookup + 10
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b27876 lookUpMethod + 34
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b24ffa _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache + 6
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b24ce4 objc_msgSend_uncached + 20
4   UIKit                           0x358b5ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
5   UIKit                           0x358b5e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
6   UIKit                           0x358b5e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
7   UIKit                           0x358b5b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
8   UIKit                           0x358b641c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 336
9   UIKit                           0x3589b52e _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 2194
10  UIKit                           0x3589abfa _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 690
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3039ca2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3039e45e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3039f754 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x35571418 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x355714c4 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x358c7d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
19  UIKit                           0x358c5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
20  MyApp                       0x0000206e main (main.m:14)
21  MyApp                       0x00002038 0x1000 + 4152

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361003ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36100fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0c03a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361003ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fdc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fd758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3039d2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3039f562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x34c2627e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ffd18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e30860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd7eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x3661d8f4 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x3661d83a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x324a9a64 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x3663b4dc figThreadMain + 156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x3662562e    r1: 0x3665003c      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x624f7473
    r4: 0x001aa690    r5: 0x3662562e      r6: 0x00000001      r7: 0x2fdfe57c
    r8: 0x3662562e    r9: 0x3edb2a18     r10: 0x001c36c0     r11: 0x001c36c0
    ip: 0x345b6ff5    sp: 0x2fdfe570      lr: 0x345b987d      pc: 0x345bd72a
  cpsr: 0x600f0030
```

And the 2nd one:

```
Date/Time:       2011-04-28 19:14:03.591 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ffa1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e093b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e01bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fca64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b2806c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fae36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fae8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363faf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b26c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x303c91b8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
10  CoreFoundation                  0x303c8642 ___forwarding___ + 502
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3033f178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3033556a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
13  UIKit                           0x358b5ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
14  UIKit                           0x358b5e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
15  UIKit                           0x358b5e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
16  UIKit                           0x358b5b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
17  UIKit                           0x358b5834 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 180
18  UIKit                           0x358b4baa -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 294
19  UIKit                           0x358b4568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
20  UIKit                           0x3589d30c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
21  UIKit                           0x3589cc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
22  GraphicsServices                0x35571e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3039ca90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3039e838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3039f606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
28  GraphicsServices                0x35571418 GSEventRunModal + 108
29  GraphicsServices                0x355714c4 GSEventRun + 56
30  UIKit                           0x358c7d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
31  UIKit                           0x358c5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
32  MyApp                       0x0000206e main (main.m:14)
33  MyApp                       0x00002038 0x1000 + 4152

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36100fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0c03a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361003ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fdc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fd758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3039d2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3039f562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x34c2627e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ffd18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e30860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd7eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x3661d8f4 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x3661d83a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x324a9a64 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x3663b4dc figThreadMain + 156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361003ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3ee4648c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x001f1dac      r7: 0x2fdfe0d4
    r8: 0x0001d6cc    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x001befb0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe0c8      lr: 0x3489b3bb      pc: 0x36b91a1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

The last one:

```
Date/Time:       2011-04-28 19:13:44.770 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x624f7473
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b2b72a prepareForMethodLookup + 10
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b27876 lookUpMethod + 34
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b24ffa _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache + 6
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b24ce4 objc_msgSend_uncached + 20
4   UIKit                           0x358b5ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
5   UIKit                           0x358b5e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
6   UIKit                           0x358b5e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
7   UIKit                           0x358b5b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
8   UIKit                           0x358b641c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 336
9   UIKit                           0x3589b52e _UIGestureRecognizerSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 2194
10  UIKit                           0x3589abfa _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver + 690
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3039ca2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3039e45e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3039f754 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x35571418 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x355714c4 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x358c7d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
19  UIKit                           0x358c5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
20  MyApp                       0x0000206e main (main.m:14)
21  MyApp                       0x00002038 0x1000 + 4152

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36100fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0c03a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fdc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fd758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3039d2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3039f562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x34c2627e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ffd18 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e30860 _pthread_cond_wait + 756
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd7eb2 pthread_cond_wait + 26
3   CoreMedia                       0x3661d8f4 WaitOnCondition + 4
4   CoreMedia                       0x3661d83a FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 66
5   MediaToolbox                    0x324a9a64 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 48
6   CoreMedia                       0x3663b4dc figThreadMain + 156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x3662562e    r1: 0x3665003c      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x624f7473
    r4: 0x00180af0    r5: 0x3662562e      r6: 0x00000001      r7: 0x2fdfe57c
    r8: 0x3662562e    r9: 0x3edb2a18     r10: 0x0019b7c0     r11: 0x0019b7c0
    ip: 0x345b6ff5    sp: 0x2fdfe570      lr: 0x345b987d      pc: 0x345bd72a
  cpsr: 0x600f0030
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does your app compile without any warnings?

If not, I'd suggest you tackle those first.

Comment: Yeah, no warnings or errors and no leaks. Only a few dead store from the sharekit framework.

Comment: Have you tested the app in airplane mode? Also have you tested on the same OS version? You might also want to check a release build rather than a debug build. The starting point should be to try to reproduce a crash, then we can figure out what is causing it. Also - have you asked Apple what the user flow was that causes the crash?

Comment: Yeah, we've tested everything on our side and cannot reproduce the crash. That's the hardest part. What do u mean by asking apple for user flow? We tried everything to make it crash, but it just won't crash on our devices. I am using the same OS as the apple tester. Thanks. It's driving us nuts. If u are willing to help, we can send u the entire code and a little money reward. See if u are willing to help and figure out what's wrong. My email is clasher@clasherstudio.com. Let me know if u are interested. Thanks again for replying.

Comment: Have emailed. When I mentioned user flow, I meant have Apple said that it crashes when you do A then B then C? But sure, I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Did you ever track this down? I just got a crash report with a similar signature.