# Over releasing or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry I am a newbie.  Is this over releasing the OverlayviewController?  Since it's autorelease and release again at dealloc.  Or it doesn't matter? Thank you for helping out.

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imageView, overlayViewController, cameraBtn;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View Controller

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Sharekit Logout button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:SHKLocalizedString(@"Logout") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logout)] autorelease];

    self.overlayViewController =
    [[[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

// as a delegate we will be notified when pictures are taken and when to dismiss the image picker
    self.overlayViewController.delegate = self;
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        cameraBtn.hidden = YES;
    }
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.imageView = nil;
    self.overlayViewController = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    [imageView release];
    [overlayViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one part that is missing is the definition of the property `overlayViewController`. If it's got the `retain` option then everything is fine.

In your `viewDidLoad`, your allocating and then autoreleasing, so this is balanced. But you also assign it to the *property* `overlayViewController`, and if it has the `retain` option (which it should in this case), then your call will retain the allocated OverlayViewController. That's exactly what you want.

In `dealloc`, you are releasing the *variable* that backs the property. This is OK and correct, your controller will get released correctly. However, it will get released even earlier: in `viewDidUnload`, you assign `nil` to the property. This will already release the controller. So by the time `dealloc` is called the `overlayViewController` variable will most likely be nil (but it may also still contain the controller, depending on how your object was used, that is, depending on whether `viewDidUnload` was called or not.

So the code as presented here is correct *if the property `overlayViewController` has the `retain` option*.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer.  The overlayViewController does have the retain option declared in the header.  So I think this is ok.  Not the problem why apple rejected the app.  Will have to look elsewhere...

Comment: @Clasher: Just curious: what was the reason Apple gave for the rejection ?

Comment: They said the app is crashing when launching, pressing any buttons...which I cannot reproduce here. Been looking for weeks...still cannot solve.  And this is the 2nd time it's been rejected.  I've posted the crash report here but no answer so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836769/app-store-crash-report . I can send you the entire code if you are wiling to help. It's driving me crazy. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think that `viewDidUnload` is called before `dealloc` every time. The documentation explains it's a method used only in low-memory conditions (when a memory warning is fired).